# Divide Large Number into Multiple Smaller Units

Tags: if-statement, math, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am new to Stack overflow but I am having logic issues with Google sheets and need some advice on how to proceed.

My goal is I have 3 cup sizes, small medium and large. Example: Small holds 50ML, Medium 100ML,Large 200ML,etc

I want to take a large number and evenly distribute it among the cups to show me how many cups I will need with the least amount of cups used. Example : 170ML = 1 Large, 0 Medium, 0 Small. I only need 1 large to hold everything. Also, 240ML would suggest 1 Large, 0 medium, 1 small. Since small can hold the remaining 40 and medium would be too big of a container.

Problem is I don't understand how to break down my original large number into the smaller number as I have to check and compare if it will fit, I also have to be able to add more if there's a remainder and as far as I know the Google sheet functions only run and represent numbers once.

I've already tried breaking it down to my large container first then in my second row with medium cups I take the first result and subtract from my large number to see if anything is left. If there is, all I can do is add 1 or set the number, I can't seem to scale it up if it requires more than 1 cup which isn't what I want.

I've been going crazy trying to find an easy solution to this but it seems to get more complex as if I need `IF` statements of some kind.

If anyone has any ideas I'd be happy to hear them out.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: Some general hints which apply no matter what approach you use to solve the problem. One is that the number of units of something is going to be a quantity divided by the size of the unit, rounded downward. (Rounding downward is usually called the "floor" function. I don't know if Google sheets call it that or something else.) The other is that the left-over part is going to be an amount minus a number of units times a unit size. E.g. the left-over, sub-big-cup amount is the original amount minus the number of big cups times the size of a big cup.

Comment: (continuing ...) Sometimes there's a "remainder" function to do that, but in any event one can always use times, minus, and the "floor" I mentioned previously.

Comment: Due to this information being for a business, I don't want to give anything confidential away, but this is what I have so far. I'm currently using Trunc() to get the first initial value, then multiply that by the current biggest bucket being calculated, subtract that from my original number, and I get the remainder. As I go down the buckets though, using smaller numbers gave me negatives if I only had enough for a extra large bucket let's say. Wondering the best way to split this up so I'm using the least cups. https://www.dropbox.com/s/suefkfda6l53imf/Screenshot_20191026-130041_Sheets.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you could use `IF` statement for example like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 IF(A2:A>=B1,    QUOTIENT(A2:A, B1), 
 IF(A2:A> C1+D1, QUOTIENT(B1, A2:A), 0)), ))
```

[image: 0]